# Built-in non-data version of property?

Tags: python

```
class Books():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__['referTable'] = 1

    @property
    def referTable(self):
        return 2

book = Books()
print(book.referTable)
print(book.__dict__['referTable'])
```

Running:

```
vic@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python3 test.py 
2
1
```

`Books.referTable` [being a data descriptor](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) is not shadowed by `book.__dict__['referTable']`:

> The `property()` function is implemented as a data descriptor.
>   Accordingly, instances cannot override the behavior of a property.

To shadow it, instead of `property` built-in descriptor i must use my own descriptor. Is there a built in descriptor like `property` but which is non-data?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What are you trying to achieve that can't be achieved by changing the way the function you are using ``@property`` on functions?

Comment: @Lattyware, i am trying to make a lazy descriptor. Sometimes i want `referTable` to be set in `__init__`. In other cases i want the descriptor to calculate the value and override the descriptor the same way it's done in `__init__`. Here (http://blog.pythonisito.com/2008/08/lazy-descriptors.html) it's made a separate descriptor for that, which would work for me. In my case i want to simplify it, using if possible a built-in descriptor, and `property` doesn't work for me.

Comment: 'Simplify it'? Could you clarify what you want to simplify? Why doesn't the example you link work for you?

Comment: If `property` would be a non-data descriptor i could use it instead of making my own. That's my simplification. Just curious if there exists a non-data version of `property` in standard modules. That's all. My question is not about a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on my comment, why not simply something like this:

```
>>> class Books():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__dict__['referTable'] = 1
...     @property
...     def referTable(self):
...         try:
...             return self.__dict__['referTable']
...         except KeyError:
...             return 2
... 
>>> a = Books()
>>> a.referTable
1
>>> del a.__dict__['referTable']
>>> a.referTable
2
```

Now, I'd like to note that I don't think this is good design, and you'd be much better off using a private variable rather than accessing `__dict__` directly. E.g:

```
class Books():
    def __init__(self):
        self._referTable = 1

    @property
    def referTable(self):
        return self._referTable if self._referTable else 2
```

In short, the answer is no, there is no alternative to `property()` that works in the way you want in the Python standard library.

Answer (score 2):

There is something very similar to a built-in non-data descriptor -- the class attribute:

```
class Books():

    referTable = 'default'

    def __init__(self, referTable=None):
        if referTable is not None:
            self.referTable = referTable


book = Books()
print(book.referTable)
# default
book.referTable = 'something specific'
print(book.referTable)
# something specific
```

If you need something more like a property (for example, you want a function to do some heavy-lifting the first time, but then use that first value for all future references), then you will need to build it yourself:

```
class OneTime(object):

    def __init__(self, method):
        self.name = method.__name__
        self.method = method

    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst is None:
            return self
        result = self.method(inst)
        inst.__dict__[self.name] = result
        return result

class Books(object):

    @OneTime
    def referTable(self):
        print 'calculating'
        return 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5

b = Books()
print b.__dict__
print b.referTable
print b.__dict__
print b.referTable
```

With the following results:

```
{}
calculating
120
{'referTable': 120}
120
```